# I want to combine data frames of different lengths and not getting repeated values or na

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I am fresh in R and looked a lot in the web but could not find the answer to what I am pursuing.

I have 4 data frames with different lengths and columns. I want to put all the columns side by side without getting NA or duplicated values as I am getting now with the code below:

```
summBC <- summary %>% 
  group_by(BuildingClass) %>% 
  summarise(TotalTIV=sum(as.numeric(TotalTIV))) #Pivot table on Building class

summOC < -summary %>% 
  group_by(OccupancyType) %>% 
  summarise(TotalTIV=sum(as.numeric(TotalTIV))) #Pivot table on Occupancy type

summCY <- summary %>% 
  group_by(City) %>% 
  summarise(TotalTIV=sum(as.numeric(TotalTIV))) #Pivot table on City

summCR <- summary %>% 
  group_by(Cresta) %>% 
  summarise(TotalTIV=sum(as.numeric(TotalTIV))) #Pivot table on Cresta

pt <- data.frame(summBC,summOC,summCY,summCR)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What would you expect to be in the place of NA values? Just blank cells?

Comment: Columns in dataframe's must be of the same length. You have to think about what to do if they are not the same length.

Comment: You might want to use `list` instead of `data.frame`

Comment: Are you looking for `mutate` rather than `summarise`

Comment: Perhaps you can find the dataframe whose `ncol` is the biggest among the 4 dataframes. We can run the logic that if the `ncol` of a dataframe is not the biggest, them we add `NA`s at the end of the dataframes. You can avoid "duplicates" or recycling of elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this may work to combine them into a single dataframe

```
summBC <- summary %>% group_by(BuildingClass) %>% summarise(TotalTIV=sum(as.numeric(TotalTIV))) #Pivot table on Building class
summBC$rn <- c(1:nrow(summBC))

summOC<-summary %>% group_by(OccupancyType) %>% summarise(TotalTIV=sum(as.numeric(TotalTIV))) #Pivot table on Occupancy type
summOC$rn <- c(1:nrow(summOC))

summCY<-summary %>% group_by(City) %>% summarise(TotalTIV=sum(as.numeric(TotalTIV))) #Pivot table on City
summCY$rn <- c(1:nrow(summCY))

summCR<-summary %>% group_by(Cresta) %>% summarise(TotalTIV=sum(as.numeric(TotalTIV))) #Pivot table on Cresta
summCR$rn <- c(1:nrow(summCR))


df <- Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, by = "rn", all = TRUE), list(summBC, summOC, summCY, summCR))
```